# Getting tag of git repository when we clone and create a new repository

Tags: git, shell, github, gitlab, gitlab-ci

If I have a git repo named A, and I create a new repo B by using repo A as a template (i.e. by cloning A), is there any way to record the tag used while cloning?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You mean you clone A from a tag (or commit) and you push on another remote?

Comment: It's not clear if this is Gitlab or Github. In Github, you creating a project from a template does not allow you to clone from another repo. For that, you need to "Import Project" and only then can you use another git repo to clone from.

In any case, if youwant to track the tag, you can include the originating tag in the Name or Description fields of the new project.

Comment: Why not just tag it?